# Gradient slider in React Native?

Tags: react-native, slider

Is it possible to implement slider with static gradient track in React Native using any 3rd party library or what-soever?

Illustrative image from Google:
[image]

Right now I'm using sldier from @react-native-community/slider, but it doesn't seem to support gradient slider track? I can customize `minimumTrackTintColor` and `maximumTrackTintColor`, but I would like to have static gradient track independent of the indicator position. I have looked into other 3rd party slider libraries as well, but encountered the same problem.

So, is there any way in any library to achieve this in React Native?

Comment: iteresting question TBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired from what @Gaurav_Roy answered above, in the end, I achieved what I wanted with react-native-gesture-responder . I positioned my custom gradient slider track and slider dot as images and used `createResponder` from the library to capture user interactions with the slider dot. Then calculated the distance between dot position and track edges to get the value.

Comment: can u give some code reference, if possible

Answer (score 2):

I dont think any package upfront gives this functionality, but you can always use [linear-gradient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient). this library, make a view with. gradient like that, and on top of that, by using position:'relative' make a cursor and slide it by using [rn-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable) . You will need to work out on that, but you can create a new functionality , and maybe publish it so that it can be used by others in future.

Hopeit helps.feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks, good idea, will try it out some day and update!

Comment: @Andry sure, will look forward to the library on npm. And do upvote and mark as accepted if you think it was helpful